# What is the time complexity for finding the percentile score of an entry in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, b-tree

We have a dynamic set ( ranks change every few minutes ). 
We want to display the percentile score of the user.

What would the time complexity in MySQL be to find the rank/percentile of the user? 
( Neglecting all the disk seeks, Assuming the whole index is in the RAM )

Does MySQL store extra information in the indexes to compute this faster?

Queries i am using:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM score_table WHERE score>X"

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM score_table;
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the query that you are using for this purpose.

Comment: Are you looking for an accurate number or is "it is extremely fast given your conditions" sufficient for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM score_table
WHERE score > X;
```

I'm pretty sure that MySQL scans the index starting at the value right after "X".  I don't think it does an optimization of counting the sizes of the leafs within the index.  So, this operation would be O(n), but would be fast because the index is in memory.

If the scores change so quickly, it is hard to think of a good data structure for calculating the rank.  Depending on how much the scores change, there might be some hacks that you can do to optimize the queries.

Comment: Scores change all the time but not all of them, Only a few rows a minute so i'm not to worried about index updates It's just that precomputing the percentile doesn't make too much sense there. But now i know i can't try to calculate the percentile on each page request. 
Maybe we'll run a periodic update.
Thank you :)

Comment: @2bigpigs . . . I'm imagining a solution where you do something like precompute decile boundaries.  Then, you keep track of changes using a trigger, but work only needs to be done when the decile changes.  Then, the counting could be within each decile, saving up to 90% of the work.  This is just a sketch of an idea, though.